# Beamer: change size of navigation dots

Tags: beamer, presentations

is there a way to change the size of the navigation dots that appear using Beamer's Singapore theme? I have used the `[compress]`option, and now the dots are too many and go outside the page, so I figured that by reducing their size I could manage to have them all back on the page.
I have looked in many different places but unfortunately I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of circles you could use a more compact miniframe, e.g

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}

\usetheme{Singapore}

\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}[tick]
\begin{document}
    

\section{title} 
\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\subsection{title}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]